# Is there a way to stack navigation screens in Curved Navigation Bar in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I want my home page to save state while navigation so that it does not load again. Is there a way to stack screens in curved navigation bar?

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: CurvedNavigationBar(
        index : 0,
        height: 60,
        items: const [
          Icon(Icons.home),
          Icon(Icons.post_add),
          Icon(Icons.person),
          Icon(Icons.settings)
        ],
        onTap: (index) {
          setState(() {
            this.index = index;
          });
        },
        animationDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
      ),
      body: screens[index],
    );
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    you need to assign the value to index property inside the CurvedNavigationBar widget and not zero ( index : 0).
    
    u can try,
    int _index;
    and in 
    initMethod(){
    _index= 0
    }
   and assign the value to above property
index: _index
so, when onTap() is called, it will update the state.
```